# show hide content with jquery

Tags: jquery, show-hide

i'm new in programming..
i want to create `show/hide` div with jquery effect.

i have two `<div>` elements,

1.`<div class="div1">`
2.`<div class="div2">` ----> i set to `hide` in my css (display:none)

this is my html code:

```
<a href="#" class="show_div_2">Div 2</a>

<div id="div1"> THIS IS DIV 1...</div>

<div id="div2"> THIS IS DIV 2...</div>
```

and this my `javascript` code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".div1").show();

    $('.show_div_2').click(function(){
      $(".div1").slideToggle('fast');
      $(".div2").slideToggle('slow');
    });

});
```

My problem is.. 
How i can bring `time interval` between `div1` and `div2` ???
In other words, i want to shown `div2` after `div1` hidden.

Help me please....
thx

Comment: You do realize your markup is wrong :) i.e. your `div1 and 2` are ids not classes hence use `#id`.

Comment: You've got something wrong there, your target `div` elements are being addressed by and `id` or by means of a `class`? You start by stating that you have a `.div1` and `.div2` _(class)_, but on the markup you have `#div1` and `#div2` _(id)_!!

Answer (score 4):

You should use the animation success callback function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $(".div1").show();

  $('.show_div_2').click(function(){
    $(".div1").slideToggle('fast', function(){
      $(".div2").slideToggle('slow');
    });
  });

});
```

Comment: Hiya there just a note: the HTML markup of OP is wrong :) and it will work as animation suppose to like this, **Made and small demo** feel free to use it :) http://jsfiddle.net/PCk7E/5/ rest you are absolutely right! cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest the following:

```
$('.show_div_2').click(
    function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); // prevents default action of the link element
        var div1 = $('#div1'), // reference to the jQuery object
            div2 = $('#div2');
        div1.fadeOut( // fades out the div of id="div1"
            function(){
                div2.fadeIn(); /* fades in the div id="div2" once the
                                  previous fadeOut has completed */
            });
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/xm5gM/).

Also, your original code had some problems, for example: `$(".div1").show();` selects all elements of `class="div1"`, none of which are present in your HTML; what you *have* got is `id="div1"`, which requires the `$('#div1')` selector type.

References:

- jQuery:

  - [`click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/).
  - [`fadeIn()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/).
  - [`fadeOut()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/).
- Selectors:

  - [CSS Selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html).
  - [jQuery Selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).

Comment: yeah i got it... thats work thanks... i use div1.slideUp and div2.slideDown  its so beautiful for me... :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".div1").slideToggle('fast',function(){
   $(".div2").slideToggle('slow');
});
```

jQuery effects have a callback what is executes when the effect is done. If you run the effect on div2 when the effect on div1 is finished, you are done.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$('.show_div_2').click(function(){
$(".div1").slideToggle('fast', function(){
  $(".div2").slideToggle('slow');
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a callback-function to the slideToogle() function like this:

```
$(".div1").slideToggle('fast', function() {
   // this function is called when the div1 slideToogle function is done
    $(".div2").slideToggle('slow'); 
});
```